# BufferedOutputStream not working with Korean characters as expected

Tags: java, outputstream, fileoutputstream, bufferedoutputstream

I'm trying to write Korean characters to a File and it's writing some gibberish data which I need to work around for showing as Korean data when I open it in CSV. How can I achieve my requirement without the workaround of decoding back to UTF-8 and show Korean data.

```
    File localExport = File.createTempFile("char-test", ".csv");
    try (
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(localExport);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter =
                    new OutputStreamWriter(bos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    ) {
        ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        rows.add("\"가짜 사용자\",사용자123,saint1_user123");
        rows.add("\"페이크유저루노도스트레스 성도1\",saint1_user1");
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            String csvUserStr = rows.get(i);
            outputStreamWriter.write(csvUserStr);
        }
    }
```

It's writing the below data instead of the one I'm actually writing to the File.

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: you need UTF_16

Comment: You're *looking* at it *how* exactly and with what value for `file.encoding`?

Comment: Use Unicode, there should all characters be defined.

Comment: I'm pretty sure UTF-8 supports korean characters.  How are you opening the csv?  Many apps (looking at you, Excel) assume it's ascii/codepage-1252/default OS encoding.  For opening CSVs with utf-8, I use File > Import and there's a wizard that follows where you can pick the encoding (aka "Origin").

Comment: You do _NOT_ need UTF-16, that is incorrect advice.

Comment: @Taylor Yes, that's the workaround I'm using to import and view the Korean data. But, it's not acceptable for our customer. The expectation is to show the data as is when they open the excel file by default instead of going though the importing.

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 is perfectly OK. I can simulate the garbage output by reading with the wrong encoding, e.g. MacRoman:`["Í∞ÄÏßú ÏÇ¨Ïö©Ïûê",ÏÇ¨Ïö©Ïûê123,saint1_user123, "ÌéòÏù¥ÌÅ¨Ïú†Ï†ÄÎ£®ÎÖ∏ÎèÑÏä§Ìä∏Î†àÏä§ ÏÑ±ÎèÑ1",saint1_user1]`

Comment: Unfortunately, what they find unacceptable is a behaviour in Excel, not your software.

Comment: Make sure the source code is compiled with the UTF-8 encoding and that you view the written file with the UTF-8 encoding (e.g. using Notepad++ you can explicitly define the encoding to view)

Comment: If the CSV file needs to be read by Excel, write the BOM first. The file will be recognized as UTF-8. Excel can also open a CSV file encoded in UTF-16-LE with the BOM. Note also that depending on language settings of the operating system on which the CSV file will be opened, the file may need a semicolon instead of a coma as field separator.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your java code. You are writing those characters, including the korean, precisely as written.

Whatever tool you are using to *look* at this file?

That's the broken one. Tell it that the file is UTF-8 based. If you can't, get a better tool or figure out which encoding it reads in, and update your java code.

Note that CSV files, text files, etc - they **do not** store the encoding that was used to write the data. All the programs that read/write to the file need to just know what encoding it is, there's no real way to know other than being told.

---

UPDATE: From a comment it looks like 'the tool that is reading this' is excel.

Excel asks for the encoding of the file when you use the 'import CSV' dialog. Pick UTF-8 in the dropdown. Depends on which version/OS you're on, but usually it's called 'File Origin'.

If you prefer that your client need not mess with the default, usually the default is something like MacRoman or Win1282, and with such an encoding, it is in fact *impossible* get korean characters. They simply aren't in that set.

if you want the fire and forget approach, generate the excel file yourself, for example using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org).

Answer (score 1):

CSV files don't have any means to carry encoding information "in-band"—in the file itself. I'm guessing the default character encoding used for Excel CSV imports is the system default, so if that isn't Korean, they will have to specify the encoding when they import the CSV. If your client requires *CSV,* they have no choice but to accept that behavior.

However, if their requirement is to open your file in Excel (and not that the file has to be CSV format), you could write an Excel spreadsheet instead. The various Excel file formats do include character encoding information, so they would be able to open the file without manually specifying the encoding.

Library recommendations are off-topic, but libraries such [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) make writing simple Excel sheets fairly easy. There are additional benefits as well, such as taking care of any necessary escaping for you, so that your file doesn't repeatedly break when unanticipated values are included in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Excel fails to detect that the text is encoded in UTF-8. One solution is to write an invisible BOM character as first one:

```
  outputStreamWriter.write("\uFEFF");
  for...
```

This is a normally superfluous and ugly marker for miscellaneous UTF encoding.

By the way take a look at the class Files, that can reduce the code to one line.